# Is there a numpy function like np.fill(), but for arrays as fill value?

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to build an array of some given shape in which all elements are given by another array. Is there a function in numpy which does that efficiently, similar to `np.full()`, or any other elegant way, without simply employing for loops?

Example: Let's say I want an array with shape
`(dim1,dim2)` filled with a given, constant scalar value. Numpy has `np.full()` for this:

```py
my_array = np.full((dim1,dim2),value)
```

I'm looking for an analog way of doing this, but I want the array to be filled with another array of shape `(filldim1,filldim2)` A brute-force way would be this:

```py
my_array = np.array([])
for i in range(dim1):
    for j in range(dim2):
        my_array = np.append(my_array,fill_array)
my_array = my_array.reshape((dim1,dim2,filldim1,filldim2))
```

**EDIT**

I was being stupid, `np.full()` does take arrays as fill value if the shape is modified accordingly:

```py
my_array = np.full((dim1,dim2,filldim1,filldim2),fill_array)
```

Thanks for pointing that out, @Arne!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41045871/10077354 Does this help you ?

Comment: You can pass an array as the `fill_value` to `np.full()`.

Comment: @Arne You're right. I tried this before, but didn't realize I need to modify the shape accordingly.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian Yes, but they actually don't mention ```np.full()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
>>> shape = (2, 3)
>>> fill_shape = (4, 5)
>>> fill_arr = np.random.randn(*fill_shape)

>>> arr =  np.tile(fill_arr, [*shape, 1, 1])

>>> arr.shape
(2, 3, 4, 5)

>>> np.all(arr[0, 0] == fill_arr)
True
```

---

**Edit**: better answer, as suggested by @Arne, directly using [`np.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html):

```
>>> arr = np.full([*shape, *fill_shape], fill_arr)                                               

>>> arr.shape                                                                                    
(2, 3, 4, 5)

>>> np.all(arr[0, 0] == fill_arr)                                                                
True
```

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions: 1) What is the difference between the two solutions? And 2) Is the asterisk required here?

Comment: The `np.full` solution is better because it is 1. more explicit 2. already generalized for any number of dimensions for the `fill_arr` array. Performances are similar (`np.full` a bit faster). And, yes, the star operator is required to unpack shapes values before repacking them into a single list, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/13636407.